# A city with four sections

Tags: riddle, word

I'm not very good at rhyming. But here is a riddle.

```
There is a city with four sections and four well.
In this city, there are 18 thieves with one queen.
There comes a policeman.
He puts each of them in the well after beating.
```

What is it?

Comment: To the downvoter, would you care to leave a comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pretty easy one

it is

> a carrom board

There is a city with four sections and four well.

> the corner holes on board

In this city, there are 18 thieves with one queen.

> the queen and 18 pieces

There comes a policeman.

> the striker

He puts each of them in the well after beating

> strike and sink the piece in to the hole